# Access Violation Exception RegEnumValue

Tags: vb.net, winapi, pinvoke

I'm using this code to enumerate all values in a registry key.

```
    Private ReadOnly HKeyLocalMachine As New IntPtr(-2147483646)
    Private Const KeyQueryValueWow64Key As Integer = &H101
    Private Const ErrorNoMoreItems As Integer = &H103
    Private Const errorSuccess As Integer = &H0

                Dim keyHandle As IntPtr = Nothing
                RegOpenKeyEx(HKeyLocalMachine, newPath, 0, KeyQueryValueWow64Key, keyHandle)

                If keyHandle = Nothing Then
                    Return "Error accessing registry key"
                End If

                Dim index As Integer = 0
                Dim valueName As New StringBuilder(1000)
                Dim valueLenght As UInteger
                Dim valueDataLenght As IntPtr

                If RegQueryInfoKey(keyHandle, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing,       Nothing, Nothing, valueLenght, valueDataLenght, Nothing, Nothing) = errorSuccess Then
                  Debug.WriteLine("SUCCESS IN REGQUERYINFOKEY")
                End If

                    Do
                        returnValue = RegEnumValue(keyHandle, index, valueName, valueLenght, Nothing, Nothing, datalenght, valueDataLenght)

                   If returnValue = errorSuccess Then
                            Debug.WriteLine("Success")
                        End If

                    index = index + 1
                Loop Until returnValue = ErrorNoMoreItems
```

Here are my API declarations:

```
 <DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
    Private Shared Function RegOpenKeyEx( _
    hKey As IntPtr, _
    subKey As String, _
    ulOptions As Integer, _
    samDesired As Integer, _
    ByRef hkResult As IntPtr _
    ) As Integer
    End Function


    <DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function RegEnumValue( _
   ByVal hKey As IntPtr, _
   ByVal dwIndex As Integer, _
   ByVal lpValueName As StringBuilder, _
   ByRef lpcValueName As UInteger, _
   ByVal lpReserved As IntPtr, _
   ByVal lpType As IntPtr, _
   ByVal lpData As IntPtr, _
   ByVal lpcbData As IntPtr _
) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("advapi32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function RegQueryInfoKey( _
hkey As IntPtr, _
ByRef lpClass As StringBuilder, _
ByRef lpcbClass As UInteger, _
lpReserved As IntPtr, _
ByRef lpcSubKeys As UInteger, _
ByRef lpcbMaxSubKeyLen As UInteger, _
ByRef lpcbMaxClassLen As UInteger, _
ByRef lpcValues As UInteger, _
ByRef lpcbMaxValueNameLen As UInteger, _
ByRef lpcbMaxValueLen As IntPtr, _
ByRef lpcbSecurityDescriptor As UInteger, _
lpftLastWriteTime As IntPtr _
) As Integer
End Function
```

And i'm getting AccessViolationException when i pass the last parameter of RegEnumValue non-null, if i pass a null IntPtr the function succeeds but no data is retrieved, only the name.
I've tried changing the API variables with no luck, the other two functions always succeed.

Comment: We've no idea what you are passing to that last parameter though. Somehow you omitted to show that.

Comment: Edited, forgot the declaration, because i'm retrieving the value from the RegQueryInfoKey call.

Comment: Why are we not using the managed RegistryKey class to do all of this?

Comment: Because i'm trying to access 32 and 64-bit keys from a 32-bit application and that's not possible in .net 3.0 .

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the code fails is that you did not initialise `valueDataLenght`. Incidentally, you mean to name this variable `valueDataLength`.

You need the `IntPtr` variable `valueDataLength` to refer to a `DWORD` that contains the length of the data buffer. Using `IntPtr` here makes life difficult for you. I'd declare the parameter like this instead:

```
ByRef lpcbData As Integer
```

Comment: You've not done it correctly. I can't see what you've done wrong from that screenshot. Keep trying.

Comment: Well, i posted all my code and debug'ed it and i can't see what am i doing wrong...

Comment: I don't know what can i try more, if i try to make the second buffer a stringbuilder too it fails with the same error, i've tried everything i can think of, i guess i'll just retrieve the key's values name's, then i P/Invoke RegQueryValueEx...
Thanks for trying to help anyway.

Comment: Well, I answered the question that you asked. I just decided not to debug the code that you wrote after that. I think your expectations are unrealistic. Your first comment to this answer set the tone all wrong in my view.

Comment: I think @DavidHeffernan is correct: looking at the screenshot you've posted, you're passing an `Integer` (`valueDataLenght` [sic]) where the function expects an `IntPtr`. It's an "in-out" parameter, so it's probably trying to write data to an invalid location (the address represented by the value of `valueDataLenght`), giving an access violation.

Comment: @icabod The screenshot is (presumably), for code modified from that in the question. At this point it is asking a lot for us to debug some other code that we can no longer see and that is a moving target.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My "tone" in the first comment? I'm sorry if you thought by that that i'm someone who expects to be spoonfed, i commented with a print of all my code except the Declarations, which are in the OP and were modified accordingly as your suggestion as specified, the first function always succeeded with all values i tried, Uint, int, intptr, the error occurs always in the RegEnumValue if i specify any non-null for the ValueData parameters, i can't figure out why... as i said, thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: I answered the question that you asked correctly and your response suggested that you did not agree and expected more. In what way is this not the answer to the question that you asked? You asked why you were getting an AV, and I told you why. Never mind.

Comment: Yes you probably did, but i also probably did mess up and the error kept throwing even with the change you suggested, so my issue continued so i posted a print to show you the exact values i was getting see'ing if you or someone could help me figure out the actual issue since in my head i've tried everything i could, i always do that before i post a question here, but i failed to found the actual issue...
Anyways, i went back to the RegQueryValueEx API with the value name's i could retrieve with RegEnumValue , thanks for the help again.

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand yet, but we are expected to answer your questions rather than solve your problems.